# Heroku run rake db error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and this is the error I'm getting. Why is this error appearing? I've done this many times before and have never seen this error.

Thanks in advance

```
Heroku client internal error.


Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
Backtrace:   /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `initialize'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `open'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `block in start'
             /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:113:in `rendezvous_session'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:100:in `run_attached'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             /Users/johndoe/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku run rake db:migrate
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.35.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: as you can see, Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT). May be the server is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens frequently with me. Just fire the command again, will work.